# Why is android status bar notification icon not showing up?

Tags: android, libgdx

I can see the notification of my app when I pull down the status bar, but no icon is showing up.
By icon I mean the small white icons like the wifi icon. I have used [Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html) to generate the icons I am using. This is the code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        String chanel_id = "3000";
        CharSequence name = "Channel";
        String description = "Disc";
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(chanel_id, name, importance);
        mChannel.setDescription(description);
        mChannel.enableLights(true);
        mChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(gameActivity.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_kb);
        mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(gameActivity, chanel_id)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_kb)
                .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(text);
    }
```

Comment: Did you fix this? I'm having the same here!

Comment: No I couldn't unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Have you called `notificationManager.notify(chanel_id, mBuilder.build());`?

Comment: Yes, I have. The notification shows up just fine, the big icons also work, only the small white icon doesnt show up.

Comment: Hi @LonelyBishop, did you find a solution to this ?

Comment: Hi. No, unfortunately.